# T-SQL Query To Get Count Of Users Who Logged In Every Day In A Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Azure SQL Database with a table Logins in this format:

| UserId | LoginDate |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 2020-07-10 19:41:51.1256874 |
| ABC123 | 2020-07-11 15:52:43.5685147 |
| XYZ789 | 2020-06-12 18:23:15.5524874 |

I need to write a query that will get the number of users that logged in every day in a month. I'm not really a SQL guy, so my first thought was to loop through the user ids and the dates in a date range and increment a counter, but I soon figured out that loops don't perform well in SQL. I have read some articles and posts about SQL being set-based, but I haven't figured out how to apply what I read to my problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would convert the login date column to a date and aggregation:

```
select convert(date, logindate), count(distinct userid)
from t
group by convert(date, logindate);
```

Note that this uses `count(distinct)`.  If a user logins in multiple times on the same day, the user only counts once.

You can add a `where` clause for a particular month.  Something like this:

```
where logindate >= '2021-01-01' and logindate < '2021-02-01'
```

for January 2021.

EDIT:

If you want the number of users who logged in every day during a specific period, then:

```
select count(*)
from (select userid, convert(date, logindate) as the_date,
             count(*) over (partition by userid) as num_dates
      from t
      where logindate >= @start and
            logindate < dateadd(day, 1, @end)
      group by userid, convert(date, logindate)
     ) u
where num_dates = datediff(day, @end, @start) + 1;
```

Or:

```
select count(*)
from (select userid,
             count(distinct convert(date, logindate)) num_dates
      from t
      where logindate >= @start and
            logindate < dateadd(day, 1, @end)
      group by userid
     ) u
where num_dates = datediff(day, @end, @start) + 1;
```

Comment: That seems to get me a count of users that logged in each day, but not a single count of users that logged in every day that month.

Comment: @JeffCren . . . I misunderstood the question.  I added a solution for any period of time, given a `@start` and `@end` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by user, filter the query for the month that you want and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SElECT UserId 
FROM Logins
WHERE CONVERT(date, LoginDate) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' -- for Jan 2021
-- or with YEAR() and MONTH()
-- WHERE YEAR(LoginDate) = 2021 AND MONTH(LoginDate) = 1 
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(date, LoginDate)) = DAY(EOMONTH(MIN(LoginDate)))
```

If you want only the number of users use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SElECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () counter 
FROM Logins
WHERE CONVERT(date, LoginDate) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' -- for Jan 2021
-- or with YEAR() and MONTH()
-- WHERE YEAR(LoginDate) = 2021 AND MONTH(LoginDate) = 1 
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(date, LoginDate)) = DAY(EOMONTH(MIN(LoginDate)))
```